# Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of undefined - what should be fixed in the script

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, console.log

I have an issue with a script that automatically clicks the follow button. 
It worked perfectly for  2-3 weeks but for the last couple of days I'm constantly receiving an error in the console. In addition, the scroll function isn't working properly either.

Here are my codes:

```js
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"; //Loads JavaScript
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
jQuery.noConflict()
```

```js
window.setInterval(function(){
var x = 0;
$("button:contains('Follow')").each(
function(){ if($(this).text()=="Follow"){
if(x==2) return false; 
$(this).trigger("click");
$('._4gt3b').scrollTop($('._4gt3b')[0].scrollHeight);
x++;}
}
)
$('._4gt3b').scrollTop($('._4gt3b')[0].scrollHeight); console.log('loop');
}, 70000);
```

Below is the error message that I'm receiving in the console:

```js
VM160:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:7:39)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at <anonymous>:3:32
```

Comment: You getting error because `._4gt3b` element is not exist. maybe JS executes before `._4gt3b` element is painted in browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TO avoid error check element is exist or not. Added a condition to check element is exist or undefined `if(typeof $('._4gt3b')[0] !== 'undefined')`

Here's the modified script with proper indention,

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  var x = 0;
  $("button:contains('Follow')").each(function(){ 
    if($(this).text()=="Follow"){
      if(x==2) return false; 
      $(this).trigger("click");
      if(typeof $('._4gt3b')[0] !== 'undefined'){
        $('._4gt3b').scrollTop($('._4gt3b')[0].scrollHeight);
      }
      x++;
    }
  });
  if(typeof $('._4gt3b')[0] !== 'undefined'){
    $('._4gt3b').scrollTop($('._4gt3b')[0].scrollHeight);
  }
  console.log('loop');
}, 70000);
```

Comment: Million Thanks to You Muthu . The error disappeared. I would be grateful also if you could help me fix the scroll issue. The script works perfect but its not executing the scrolling down command . What can be the solution ? THanks in advance

Comment: If you don't mind , can you tell me how to do that ? I googled it and didn't manage to find sth useful . Should I inspect the page HTML check  that ?       P.S. By the way , Its a follow script for instagram if that helps . Thanks a lot once again  Muthu for your patience and help

Comment: yes, use inspect to check whether that element is exist or not

Comment: It doesn't exist... any further ideeas ?

Comment: Ok. So error is caused because of missing element `._4gt3b`. My solution is not to stop JS execution. You need to think for further steps.

Comment: Is there a way to find the right element that is responsible for scrolling the following list ? Thanks

Comment: Please, can you help me to find out what is the element ? THanks

Comment: Please post this as another question in Stackoverflow and someone will help you.